# rhandsontable with html tags

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I am trying to create a handsontable widget using the `rhandsontable()` function from the `rhandsontable` package with custom html. The following code does not render the column as html:

```
VoyInfo$Details <- paste0("<b>","DWT: ","</b>", VoyInfo$dwt, "<br>",
                          "<b>", "IceClass: ", "</b>", VoyInfo$IceClass, "<br>",
                          "<b>", "IMO: ", "</b>", VoyInfo$imo_no, "<br>",
                          "<b>", "Vessel Type: ", "</b>", VoyInfo$VesselType)
```

However using the `DT` package, I can render this successfully as html by using `datatable(VoyInfo, escape=FALSE)`. Is there something akin to the `escape` argument in `rhandsontable`?

Comment: Look at the section **Custom renderer** in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhandsontable/vignettes/intro_rhandsontable.html).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent thanks. Had a look and was able to solve it using `rhandsontable(VslInfo, rowHeaders = NULL) %>% hot_col(3, renderer = htmlwidgets::JS("safeHtmlRenderer"))`, with `Details` being the third column.